# mongoexport and specific fields export with an alias name

Tags: mongodb, mongoexport

I am trying to export certain fields from a collection using mongoexport command, by defining the fields in an external file.
Is there a possible way to define an alias for each of the field.
Example:

```
{
 "id":1,
 "words":["data","base"]
}
```

My file would be as:

```
id
words.0
words.1
```

Which leads to a csv header as :

> id, words.0, words.1

Instead, I require aliases to each of these transformed columns as:

> id, first_word, second_word

Comment: Mongoexport doesn't have a feature to provide alias for the field names.

Comment: If that so, are there any alternatives to provide alias field names to the flat-files??

Comment: And I've also opened an enhancement request in JIRA, for this specific functionality. Let's see what turns out.

Comment: Too bad, the enhancement request has been stalled for now! :(